# Reflexivity of $X \times Y$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I want to prove the following

> **Theorem.** Let $X,Y$ be reflexive. Then $X \times Y$ is reflexive.

Here my try.

*Proof.* Let $J_X, J_Y$ be the canonical injections of $X$ onto $X''$ and of $Y$ onto $Y''$ respectively. Define $J := ( J_X, J_Y )$ (in the sense that $J(x,y) = ( J_X (x), J_Y (y) )$ for all $(x,y) \in X\times Y$). Thus $J : X\times Y \to X'' \times Y''$ and $J$ is surjective, so that $X'' \times Y''$ is reflexive.

Now, if we show that $X'' \times Y''$ and $(X \times Y)''$ are isometrically isomorphic, we have done. Assume that $K : X \times Y \to (X \times Y)''$ is the canonical injection of $X\times Y$ into $(X \times Y)''$. Since $J$ is an isometric isomorphism, we have that $K \circ J^{-1} : X'' \times Y'' \to (X \times Y)''$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Does it work? I'm not really sure about my last statements.

Edit - Last part deleted (I answered myself!)

Comment: I don't know if the last part (the one with $K$) is correct, perhaps it is, but it is a bit too complicated for me. I would simply identify $(X\times Y)'$ with $X'\times Y'$ by setting $$f(x, y)=f_1(x)+f_2(y)$$
where $f_1(x)=f(x, 0)$ and $f_2(y)=f(0, y)$. Iterating the construction, $$(X\times Y)''\equiv X''\times Y''$$ and you are done. Does it convince you?

Comment: It was my first approach! However, I was not completely sure about the identification, beacuse I was in doubt if $f(x,y) = f_1(x) + f_2(y)$ was an isomorphism (being sum of isomorphisms, it should be but the inverse seems a little strange to me), so after several attempts I chose the second way.

Comment: Take a look [at this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148906/the-reflexivity-of-the-product-lpi-times-lpi?rq=1)

Comment: @Federico: You are right, the fact that the proposed identification is an isometric isomorphism is not entirely obvious and should be proven explictly. For those things I like to refer [to the lecture notes by Gianni Gilardi](http://www-dimat.unipv.it/gilardi/WEBGG/PSPDF/analfunz1011.pdf), theorem 3.10 at page 60. (in Italian)

Comment: @Norbert Thank you, I read that question before posting; a key point is that the author uses H\"older inequality to show that $(X \times Y)' = X' \times Y'$, and so the conclusion is straightforward by iteration, but this is a feature of $L^p$ spaces. I would consider the general case, so the identification is not (or more precisely, doesn't appear to me) so "easy".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for reference, the proof now follows immediately by theorem 3.10 and your first comment.

Comment: Also: A Banach space is reflexive if and only if every bounded subset is relatively weakly compact. The weak topology on a product is the product of the weak topologies.

Comment: @Federico may be you could post an answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post two proofs, the first completes the one in my question and the other is deduced from references in comments.

> **Proposition.** $K \circ J^{-1}$ in proof of the theorem in question is an isometric isomorphism.

*Proof.* Since $K$ is an isometry, follows that $K \circ J^{-1}$ is an isometry. Now we have to show that it is surjective. Given an element $H \in ( X \times Y )''$, we can construct an element of $X'' \times Y''$ by imposing 
\begin{equation}
H(f(x,\cdot)) =: u(x), H(f(\cdot, y)) =: v(y)
\end{equation}

and definining $L := (u, v)$, in the sense that $L(x,y) = (u(x), v(y))$ for all $(x,y) \in X\times Y$. 
So to each element in $(X \times Y)''$ is associated a pair in $X'' \times Y''$. Hence $K\circ J^{-1}$ is surjective. $\square$

Here is another proof (taken and translated from reference provided by @GiuseppeNegro), based on the following

> **Lemma.** Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $X', Y'$ their duals. Then $(X \times Y)'$ and $X' \times Y'$ are isometrically isomorphic.

*Proof*. Let $T: X' \times Y' \to (X \times Y)'$ be defined by

\begin{equation}
\langle T(f,g) , (x,y) \rangle := \langle f,x \rangle + \langle g,y \rangle \quad f \in X', \, g \in Y'
\end{equation}

Then define $\phi : X \times Y \to \mathbb K$ by

\begin{equation}
\phi( x,y ) := \langle f,x \rangle + \langle g,y \rangle, \quad x \in X, \, y \in Y.
\end{equation}

It is clear that $T$ is linear. Moreover, it is surjective. In fact, given $\phi \in ( X \times Y)'$, we can define functionals

\begin{equation}
f(x) := \langle \phi, (x,0) \rangle, \, g(y) := \langle \phi, (0,y) \rangle, \quad x \in X, \, y \in Y ,
\end{equation}

so that $f \in X'$, $g \in Y'$ and $\phi = T(x,y)$. Now it remains to show that $T$ is an isometry. For $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ we have

\begin{equation}
\lvert \phi(x,y) \rvert \leq \lvert \langle f , x \rangle \rvert + \lvert \langle g , y \rangle \rvert \leq \lVert f \rVert \lVert x \rVert + \lVert g \rVert \lVert y \rVert \leq (\lVert f \rVert ^2 + \lVert g \rVert^2 )^{1/2}(\lVert x \rVert ^2 + \lVert y \rVert^2 )^{1/2} ,
\end{equation}

and by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for the euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$,

\begin{equation}
\lVert \phi \rVert \leq \lVert (f,g) \rVert \lVert (x,y) \rVert.
\end{equation}

Conversely, we prove that, for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\lVert \phi \rVert \geq \lVert (f,g)\rVert - 2\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary. By definition of $\lVert f \rVert$, there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that $\lVert x_0 \rVert = 1$ and $\lvert \langle f, x_0 \rangle \rvert \geq \lVert f \rVert - \epsilon$. Let $\theta \in \mathbb R$ such that $\langle f, x_0 \rangle = \lvert \langle f, x_0 \rangle \rvert e^{i \theta}$ and set $x = e^{-i\theta} \lVert f \rVert x_0$. Then $\lVert v \rVert = \lVert f \rVert$ and

\begin{equation}
\langle f, x \rangle = e^{-i\theta}\lVert f \rVert x_0 = \lVert f \rVert \langle f, x_0 \rangle \geq \lVert f \rVert ( \lVert f \rVert - \epsilon ) = \lVert f \rVert^2 - \epsilon \lVert x \rVert.
\end{equation}

A similar construction can be carried out also for $g$, so that

\begin{equation}
\langle \phi, (x,y) \rangle = \langle f, x \rangle + \langle g,y\rangle \geq \lVert f \rVert^2 + \lVert g \rVert^2 
- ( \lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert ) = ( \lVert f \rVert^2 + \lVert g \rVert^2 )^{1/2} ( \lVert x \rVert^2 + \lVert y \rVert^2 )^{1/2} - ( \lVert x \rVert + \lVert y \rVert ) \geq \lVert ( f,g) \rVert \lVert ( x,y) \rVert - \epsilon \lVert ( x,y) \rVert
\end{equation}

and hence the result. $\square$

The identification required now follows by iteration.

In retrospect, I believe that the idea is the same for both the proofs. If my proof was correct (I think it should be now), it is much simpler than the other, because it is easier to verify that the operators involved are isometries. Please, inform me about any mistake you'll find. (my examination in functional analysis is very near!)